# does multithread conflict with Map in F#

Tags: multithreading, dictionary, f#, parallel-processing, block

```
let len = 25000000
let map = Map.ofArray[|for i =1 to len do yield (i,i+1)|]
let maparr = [|map;map;map;map|]
let f1 i =   
    for i1 =1 to len do
        let l1 = maparr.[i-1].Item(i1)
        ()

let index = [|1..4|]
let _ = index |> Array.Parallel.map f1
printf "done"
```

I found that only one core is working at full speed be the code above . But what i except is all the four thread is working together with a high level of cpu usage. So it seems multithread conflict with Map, am i right? If not, how can achieve my initial goal? Thank you in advance

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you are creating a truly ridiculous amount of data - so you aren't even getting up to the `Array.Parallel`.  This is particularly obvious as `let l1 = ...` will fail when `i=5`.

Comment: Also - I think you need to demonstrate what you actually want to do - Your questions read like the classic example of the XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Confirming - setting a smaller len will throw exceptions quite quickly - you are never even getting to f1 with that len.

Comment: Sorry guys.I have update the code. BY the way. what i really what is to make four threads read four Maps at the same time. But the CPU usage show that only one CPU is running at high speed. So i want to know whether this can be achieved. Thank you all again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you were tripping a heuristic where the library assumed when there were only a small number of tasks, it would be fastest to just use a single thread.

This code maxes out all threads on my computer:

```
let len = 1000000
let map = Map.ofArray[|for i =1 to len do yield (i,i+1)|]
let maparr = [|map;map;map;map|]
let f1 (m:Map<_,_>) =
    let mutable sum = 0
    for i1 =1 to len do
        let l1 = m.Item(i1)
        for i = 1 to 10000 do
            sum <- sum + 1
    printfn "%i" sum

let index = [|1..40|]
printfn "starting"
index |> Array.map (fun t -> maparr.[(t-1)/10]) |> Array.Parallel.iter f1
printf "done"
```

Important changes:

1. Reduced len significantly.  In your code, almost all the time was spent creating the matrix.
2. Actually do work in the loop.  In your code, it is possible that the loop was optimised to a no-op.
3. Run many more tasks.  This tricked the scheduler into using more threads and all is good